# How to reshape pixel list into RGB matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 300 numpy array of values, where the first 100 are Red pixel values , the second 100 Green and the last 100 Blue, is there quick way using reshape to rearrange this initial 1x300 list into a 100x3 matrix where each line contains the matching RGB values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more manageable, let's suppose that you have a numpy array, `pix`, with 30 values, the first ten of which are red, then 10 green, then 10 blue.  For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pix = np.arange(30)
>>> pix
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29])
```

To reshape that into a 10x3 array of RGB values, use:

```
>>> pix.reshape(3, 10).transpose()
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 1, 11, 21],
       [ 2, 12, 22],
       [ 3, 13, 23],
       [ 4, 14, 24],
       [ 5, 15, 25],
       [ 6, 16, 26],
       [ 7, 17, 27],
       [ 8, 18, 28],
       [ 9, 19, 29]])
```